# How to make sure that the pod will not schedule again to the node on which it preexisted in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

We are using multiple clusters with 30+ nodes in each. Would like to know that when we reschedule/delete a pod, it needs to go to a different node than it was on. Can you please advise a way for that?

1. How we can pass such affinity label?
2. Something needs to differentiate the worker where the deleted pod was originally, and all other workers for the cluster?

Node affinity or taints are not sufficient in this situation

Comment: It sounds like a strange situation. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Its ok if no other way than tainting a node.